# Rewrite Rules for nginx Server

Tags: nginx

So instead of using the http://www.domain.com/index.php?q=keyword which don't look really nice, I want to use http://www.domain.com/keyword which looks much nicer

Can anyone help me with the url rewrite rule for nginx?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What previous questions/answers have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?q=$1 break;
```